# Как сделать систему лайков в bitrix?

Tags: php, битрикс

Пытаюсь сделать систему лайков на cms битрикс, 
принцип такой: 
    **1)** При заходе на страницу, посетителю выводятся блоки с информацией за которую можно проголосовать. 
    **2)** При клике на лайк, значение становиться +1 
    **3)** При повторном клике, значение -1 
    **4)** Каждый раз как только был совершен клик, делается AJAX запрос, который изменяет значение свойства элемента инфоблока и увеличивает или уменьшает счетчик лайков.

Завел инфоблок с значение свойств: 
**1)** Лайки - тип число 
**2)** Ссылка на фотографию - тип строка 
**3)** Имя пользователя - тип строка 
**4)** ID того, кто лайкнул - тип список

Единственное что осталось, так это добавлять id пользователя в список когда он ставит лайк,
что бы отследить посетителя и не дать возможность сделать повторный лайк при перезагрузке страницы (или ip если пользователь не зарегистрирован).

**Вопрос именно в этом, как добавить в значение свойства типа "множественную строку" информацию и как удалить, заранее спасибо.**

Так это выглядит: https://www.zelenyjostrov.ru/contest-pictures.php

Comment: Я бы рекомендовал для вашего случая использовать множественную строку. Со свойством типа список можно заморочиться сильно особенно при его обработке в дальнейшем. С множественной строкой будет гораздо проще и комфортнее работать. Для добавления свойства смотрите https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/iblock/classes/ciblockproperty/add.php.

Comment: @NikolajSarry Изменил на множественную строку.
Подскажите на примере как добавить значение свойству например WhoIsLike вразумить не могу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь методом `SetPropertyValuesEx()` как им пользоваться есть примеры в [документации](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/iblock/classes/ciblockelement/setpropertyvaluesex.php).

Вот общий пример как работать с этим методом для множественной строки:

```
$PROPERTY_VALUE = array(
  0 => array("VALUE"=>"значение","DESCRIPTION"=>"описание значения"),
  1 => array("VALUE"=>"значение2","DESCRIPTION"=>"описание значения2") 
);
CIBlockElement::SetPropertyValuesEx($ELEMENT_ID, $IBLOCK_ID, array($PROPERTY_CODE => $PROPERTY_VALUE));
```

Comment: Прочитал документацию, порядка пары часов пробовал обновить значение множественной строки, тщетно.

Подскажите пожалуйста предметней: 
    1) Инфоблок "Конкурс картинок" - id 26. 
    2) Элемент "Картинка от пользователя №1" - id 68148. 
    3) Значение свойства "WhoIsLike".

Comment: в качестве $PROPERTY_CODE передаете код свойствао WhoIsLike которое отображается на вкладве "Свойства" в настройках инфоблока в колонке "Код поля" или "Символьный код". В качестве значения передаете свои данные.

Comment: Вместо кода св-ва использовал его наименование, проблема решена
https://savepice.ru/full/2018/6/15/ce3ffd1ad998ef2315ddb51a7e92bbb0-full.png.html

Answer (score 1):

Можно также во множественной строке хранить не ID пользователей, а ip - тогда лайки могут ставить и неавторизованные пользователи, свойство типа список для этого не при

Comment: Спасибо но, Nikolaj Sarry уже подсказал по поводу этого, а насчет ip в вопросе это описано